# Cannot use custom permalinks in wordpress when proxying request to a sub folder

Tags: wordpress, apache, permalinks

We have a setup where a main site lives on one (aws) server, say [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). We then run a wordpress blog on another aws server in the /blog subdirectory [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog)

On the main server, we proxy the /blog request to the other server with apache like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
ProxyPass /blog/ https://xx.xxx.x.xxx/siteA/
ProxyPassReverse /blog/ https://xx.xxx.x.xxx/siteA/
ProxyPass /blog https://xx.xxx.x.xxx/siteA/
ProxyPassReverse /blog https://xx.xxx.x.xxx/siteA/
...
</VirtualHost>
```

This works and the blog displays.... but only if the permalinks are set to 'plain'. If we set them to anything else then we just get a 404 response.

To further complicate matters, the blog server holds a number of different blogs in the following structure

- /var/www/blog/siteA
- /var/www/blog/siteB
- /var/www/blog/siteC

The virtual host setup on the blog server is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
DocumentRoot /var/www/blog
<Directory "/var/www/blog/siteA/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

the .htaccess file on the blog is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried various combinations for the rewrite base and the virtual host setup but I can't seem to get anywhere - those custom permalinks never work.

Comment: so permalinks alone is your problem ?, that is to say the /blog works perfectly fine otherwise with default structure ?

Comment: @PIngu - yes that is correct, the blog functions perfectly with the permalinks set to plain, but not if set to anything else. When set to anything else even the blog home page gives a 404

Comment: as far as i know, the once inside the /blog the wordpress should takover any request unless otherwise modified by apache. That being said, if apache is set normally the only thing modifying your wordpress must be the wordpress only. So check the file server for write permissions. Start by checking the write permissions of /blog directory. https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions . Give access to the web server to modify content in the sub folder installation. That should probably work.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles on the same issue. I tried changing the persmissions but even 777 didn't work.

in the end the solution was to add 'ProxyPreserveHost On' to virtual host on the main server, and to include the 'blog' sub folder on the proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /blog/ https://xx.xxx.x.xxx/siteA/blog/
ProxyPassReverse /blog/ https://xx.xxx.x.xxx/siteA/blog/
ProxyPass /blog https://xx.xxx.x.xxx/siteA/blog/
ProxyPassReverse /blog https://xx.xxx.x.xxx/siteA/blog/
```